# Django: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm getting **AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get'** in Django, I am trying to get the favorite movie genres of the user.
My form looks like this:

```
class GenresForm(forms.ModelForm):
   firstGenre = forms.CharField(label="What is your favorite genre?", widget=forms.Select(choices=GENRE_CHOICES))
   secondGenre = forms.CharField(label="What is your second favorite genre?", widget=forms.Select(choices=GENRE_CHOICES))
   thirdGenre = forms.CharField(label="What is your third favorite genre?", widget=forms.Select(choices=GENRE_CHOICES))

class Meta:
    model = Favorites
    fields = ["firstGenre", "secondGenre", "thirdGenre"]
```

My view:

```
def genres(request):
  user = request.user
  if request.method == "POST": 
      form = GenresForm(request.POST) 
      if form.is_valid():
          genres = form.save(commit=False)
          genres.user = request.user
          genres.save() 
          return redirect("/home") 
  else: 
      form = GenresForm(request.user) 
  return render(request, 'core/genres.html', {"form":form})
```

and my Model

```
class Favorites(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  firstGenre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  secondGenre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  thirdGenre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think u need `request.user` in the form

```
else: 
      form = GenresForm(request.user)
```

change it to

```
else: 
      form = GenresForm()
```

as u r not initializing the form with the user. as there is no code.